# Convolution layer padding difference between pytorch and tensorflow

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

```
torch.nn.Conv2d(7, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3))
```

In the above line of code for convolution in pytorch what is happening with the padding = (3,3) parameter. How can we implement the same padding in tensorflow.

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(7, 64, stride = (2,2), padding="same padding as pytorch")
```

How can we implement this in tensorflow ?

Answer (score 0):

The Padding is adding extra bytes on each dimension in the image. As per the documentation,

> padding controls the amount of implicit zero-paddings on both sides
> for padding number of points for each dimension.

In Tensorflow, you can use [tf.pad](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad) to do the same. For example to do `padding=(3, 3)` similar to pytorch, you can use below code -

```
import tensorflow as tf

image = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
paddings = tf.constant([[3, 3,], [3, 3]])

image = tf.pad(image, paddings, "CONSTANT")
print(image)
```

**Output-**

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]], shape=(8, 9), dtype=int32)
```